# Postgres - JSONB - Nested Columns - Query Nested Jsonb array column

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have a table with the following structure -

```
Column Name | Data Type
--------------------------
user_id     | uuid
profile     | jsonb
```

An example profile field would be something like -

`{ "data": { "races": [ "white", "asian" ] } }`

I want to query this table for users contain one of the following races (for example) - "white", "african american"

I would expect my example user above to be returned since their races field contains "white".

I have tried something like this with no success -

```
SELECT user_id from table
WHERE profile -> 'data' ->> 'races' = ANY('{"white", "african american"}')
```

Using Postgres 13.x

Thank you!

Comment: You have a typo in your JSONB. The key is `data:`. It should be `data`. That doesn't fix your problem.

Comment: Good catch.  Just fixed.  Any thoughts on a solution to this problem @Schwern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** use the [`?|` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

---

There's two problems with your query.

`->>` returns `text` not jsonb. So you're asking if the *text* `["white", "asian"]` matches `white` or `african american`.

You probably did that because otherwise you got type errors trying to use `any` with JSONB. `any` wants a Postgres array of things to compare, and it has to be an array of jsonb. We can do that...

```
select user_id
from user
where profile -> 'data' -> 'races' = ANY(array['"white"', '"african american"']::jsonb[]);
```

But this has the same problem as before, it's checking if the json array `[ "white", "asian" ]` *equals* `"white"` or `"african american"`.

You need an operator which will match against each element of the JSON. Use the [`?|` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

```
select user_id
from users
where profile -> 'data' -> 'races' ?| array['white', 'african american'];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the `?|` operator:

```
select user_id 
from my_table
where profile -> 'data' -> 'races' ?| array['white', 'african american']
```

According to [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

> jsonb ?| text[] -> boolean
>
> Do any of the strings in the text array exist as top-level keys or array elements?